# Multiplex multiple services on same port discriminating by source port

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

imagine that on the same host I have 2 services:
an ssh daemon listening on port 22
a socks5 proxy listening on port 1080

I want to multiplex both services using only port 22 but depending on the source port.

For example: if source port is one of (1,2,3,4,5,6) then it goes to 1080
otherwise it does to port 22

This rule works one way

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m multiport --sports 1,2,3,4,5,6 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1080
```

But I don't know what rule to put for the way back.

I suppose something along the lines of:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp .....
```

But I don't seem to get the right one.

Update: this seems to work for a single port:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 --sport 2 -j DNAT --to :1080
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here we go:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m multiport --sports 1:6 -j DNAT --to :1080
```

I knew it was simple.